# await channel.edit returns 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'edit' (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I recently came across this error in my discord bot's code when I tried to edit a voice channel using the bot:
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'edit'`

I've tried lots of different fixes, but none of them worked.

**Code:**

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot now online as:")
    print(bot.user)
    while True:
        response = requests.get(
            'https://api.minehut.com/server/permarpg?byName=true')

        json_data = response.json()
        if response and response.status_code == 200:
            isonline = json_data['server']['online']
            channel = bot.get_channel(id=int(1001487650517172295))
            if isonline == True:
                await channel.edit(name="Status: Online") #Error occurs here
                return True
            if isonline == False:
                await channel.edit(name="Status: Offline") #Error occurs here
                return False
        time.sleep(305)
```

Comment: [`get_channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.get_channel) will return `None` if no channel is found. Make sure that the channel exists, that your bot has permission to access it and that the ID is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line where you fetch the channel returns None instead of a channel which means the id you are using is probably invalid. You can try this:

`_channels = bot.get_all_channels()` 
`for _ch in _channels:` 
    `if _ch.name == some_name: #or maybe use a regex if you want` 
        `pass #do stuff` 
Also consider checking their API reference: [Discord Py API](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html). It's a really useful guide.